# Count how many times each number occurs in an array (positive and negative values)

Tags: java, arrays, counting

I'm working on an assignment that is dealing with arrays and I've almost completed it but I've gotten stuck on counting every element in an array (positive and negative) without using a sort, hashmap, or list of some sort. I have to be able to only use basic java techniques. My code works for all positive values but I've neglected to figure out how to count for negative numbers.. Can someone shed some light as to how I can fix my code so that it can take the whole range of positive and negative integers? Thanks!

```
public static void countArray(int[] arr){
    int[] count = new int[arr.length];
    int temp = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        temp = arr[i];
        count[temp]++;
    }
    for(int i = 1; i < count.length; i++){
        if(count[i] > 0 && count[i] == 1){
            System.out.printf("%d occurs %d time\n", i, count[i]);
        }else if(count[i] >= 2){
            System.out.printf("%d occurs %d times\n", i, count[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, then you'll need to write your own sorting algorithm, I guess.

Comment: You could use even indices in `count[]` for positive values and odd indices for negative values.  Just need to map the values to indices properly during counting, and back during reporting.

Comment: Either use a second array for negative numbers (invert them), or add an offset to each number before storing them in the already existing array. The offset needs to be - int Max.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: “code works for all positive values”.   Actually, it doesn’t. If I provide you the array [100, 200, 100, 100], it can only kept track of the count of numbers between 0 & 3, and when it counts the first 100, you’ll get an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception.  And while it may count 0’s, it won’t report the number of zeros found.

Comment: _"Why the downvotes?"_ -- You are asking us to do your work for you and tell you how to write your code.  Please visit the [help] and read [ask] to learn how to use StackOverflow.  Hint: "How do I do X" (with no evidence you've attempted it) is off topic.  Conversely "I wrote this code to do X but it fails _in this specific manner_ which I don't understand" (including all error messages and stack trace, etc) is on-topic.

Comment: Any time I see someone use the identifier `arr` I assume they are a pirate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You somehow have to map the values to values in your array of counts. Since you can't use a map, you could use another array to contain the mapping from values you're counting to indices in the counts array:

```
public static void count(int[] numbers) {
    int[] counts = new int[numbers.length];
    int[] mapping = new int[numbers.length];
    int mappings = 0; // how many mappings are used

    // map them
    for (int number : numbers) {
        boolean found = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < mappings; i++) {
            if (number == mapping[i]) {
                found = true; // already mapped
            }
        }
        if (!found) {
            mapping[mappings++] = number; // add a new mapping
        }
    }

    // count them
    for (int number : numbers) {
        int mapped = 0;
        boolean found = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < mappings; i++) {
            if (number == mapping[i]) {
                found = true;
                mapped = i; // found the mapping
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found) throw new IllegalStateException("can't happen");
        counts[mapped]++;
    }

    // print them
    for (int i = 0; i < mappings; i++) {
        int number = mapping[i];
        int count = counts[i];
        System.out.format("%,d occurs %d time%s%n", number, count, count==1?"":"s");
    }
}
```

The mappings array won't be fully used if there are any duplicates, which is why we need to separately track how many mappings are used rather than looping up to `mapping.length`.

Answer (score -2):

You can use a `Map<Integer,Integer>` to hold the counts, or do a first pass to compute the minimum value, and increment `count[temp-min]`.

UPDATE:

Actually, you would need to compute the min an max value, and allocate an array of a length of `max-min+1`.

UPDATE 2:

```
public static void countArray(int[] arr){
    if (arr != null && arr.length > 0) {
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
            if (arr[i] < min) {
                min = arr[i];
            }
            if (arr[i] < max) {
                max = arr[i];
            }
        }
        int[] count = new int[max-min+1];
        int temp = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            temp = arr[i];
            count[temp-min]++;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < count.length; i++){
            if(count[i] == 1){
                System.out.printf("%d occurs %d time\n", i-min, count[i]);
            }else if(count[i] >= 2){
                System.out.printf("%d occurs %d times\n", i-min, count[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: He may not use built-in classes that do the work if I understand that correctly.

Comment: OP says he can’t use a Map

Comment: Op mentioned that, can not used map data structure.

Answer (score -2):

Like what maja suggested, you could split into two arrays.

```
public static void countArray(int[] arr){
    int[] positiveIntCounts = new int[Integer.MAX_VALUE];
    int[] negativeIntCounts = new int[Integer.MAX_VALUE];
    int max;
    int min;

    int temp = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        temp = arr[i];
        if (temp >= 0) {
            positiveIntCounts[temp]++;
            if (temp > max) {
                max = temp;
            }
        }
        else {
            negativeIntCounts[-temp]++;
            if (temp < min) {
                min = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++){
        if (count[i] == 1){
            System.out.printf("%d occurs %d time\n", i, count[i]);
        }else if(count[i] >= 2){
            System.out.printf("%d occurs %d times\n", i, count[i]);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= -max; i++){
        if (count[i] == 1){
            System.out.printf("%d occurs %d time\n", -i, count[i]);
        }else if(count[i] >= 2){
            System.out.printf("%d occurs %d times\n", -i, count[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `new int[Integer.MAX_VALUE]` ***YIKES!***

Comment: @DavidConrad Actually I do agree it's disgusting, but being an assignment, I think what's important is correctness. Yes, it definitely is possible to loop through the array once to find the min and max value first before instantiating these two arrays, but I'm too lazy to write that. Of course, they are definitely better ways to do this, like using 3 dimensional arrays and so on.